# How to make things stay on animated character

Tags: rigging

How do you make it so something like a pair of glasses stays on a rigged character model in cycles? Whenever I move my character I want the glasses to stay on them. I have tried parenting the object but it just makes it disappear and do a bunch of weird stuff like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *parent* the glasses to the Head Bone. So then, when the animated character moves, the glasses move with the head.
So first, select the Glasses, then  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>to select the armature. Then go into *Pose mode* of the armature and select only the head bone. After that, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to parent the Object to Selected Bone